# Python: How to tokenize every type of URL paths?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, nltk

I have a dataframe of website urls and I need to first extract url domains (e.g. google.com) and url paths (e.g. foo/foo2/foo3/sjj.html), and second to tokenize the path part of the urls. The problem is that they can be in any of the following forms:

```
1- https://www.politics.com/watch?v=4PykB_cU 
(desired output: [watch])

2- https://www.politics.com/video/2014/USA/hello_world_how_are_you
(desired output: [video, USA, hello, world, how, are, you])

3- https://www.politics.com/video/2014/USA/hello-world-how-are-you
(desired output: [video, USA, hello, world, how, are, you])

4- https://www.politics.com/video/2014/USA/helloworldhowareyou
(desired output: [video, USA, hello, world, how, are, you]

5- https://www.politics.com/video/2014/USA/HelloWorldHowAreYou
(desired output: [video, USA, Hello, World, How, Are, You]

6- https://www.politics.com/1VOuFvY
(desired output: [])
```

Is there any function or package that can automatically parse and tokenize all these types of url paths?

Answer (score 1):

First three can be accomplished with string.split()

Fifth you can split in the capital letter with regex or just iterating through.

Fourth one will require much more effort. The only method I can think of is entity recognition with the entire English dictionary as entities to match, and even then you’ll need to disambiguate some conflicting matches.

Comment: Thanks. I know how to individually take of the first four types. But am looking for sth that can automatically identify each type and tokenize it accordingly (if exists).

Comment: Ah, I hear you. Haven’t heard of one. I’ll look around